# ¿Por qué cuando ejecuto mi macro paso por paso (f8) termina bien la maccro y al ejecutar el codigo completo me marca error?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una macro que copia y pega datos de excel a word, pero al momento de correrlo paso a paso lo termina bien y al ejecutarlo completo me marca error:

> Rum-Time '4605', this method or property is not available because the
>   clipboard is empty or not valid

Este es el código de la macro:

```
Sub copiar_word()
Dim wordapp As Object
Dim x, a As Integer
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
With wordapp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
End With
x = 8
Do While x <= 137
    If ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
        x = x + 1
    Else
        Do While ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value = ""
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Excel estas utilizando?

Comment: Estoy ultilizando el Excel 2013, creo que es la versión 15

Comment: Puedes resolverlo de una manera limpia usando un error handler. Aquí hay un ejemplo: [You receive run-time error 4248, 4605 or 5941 when you try to change properties on an unopened document in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813983/you-receive-run-time-error-4248,-4605-or-5941-when-you-try-to-change-properties-on-an-unopened-document-in-word) habla de Word, pero se puede usar en Excel y si quieres preguntas sólo por el error 4605 en el handler. Pero ya que es un error handler, construye una función y revisa si no hay error antes de proceder a algo.

Comment: Tenia un problema similar con la ejecucion completa al duplicar una hoja en un libro nuevo debia romper los vinculos con el libro de origen de la hoja. Finalizaba la macro y el nuevo libro seguia teniendo el vinculo. Le agregue el delay que sugiere en este problema y se me soluciono. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo dos temas que pueden ser fuente de problemas en tu macro.

La primera es que normalmente crear un nuevo documento en word toma un pequeño período de tiempo. Cuando ejecutas la macro apretando F8, ese período de tiempo es el suficiente para que el archivo esté creado, pero al ejecutar la macro directamente no, por lo que yo añadiría un delay en tu macro justo después del comando que crea el word (estoy usando 2 segundos y me funciona bien, tú puedes modificar ese delay).

Por otro lado, tienes un problema en el loop que usas cuando la celda está vacía. Si todas las celdas hacia abajo están vacías, x avanza sin límite, por lo que se queda sin recursos. Debes limitar que x sea menor o igual a 137 en ese caso también.

Dicho todo esto, el código sería el siguiente:

```
Sub copiar_word()
Dim wordapp As Object
Dim x, a As Integer
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
With wordapp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
End With
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
x = 8
Do While x <= 137
    If ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
        x = x + 1
    Else
        Do While ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value = "" And x <= 137
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Con el codigo que me compartiste ayuda, pero sigue marcando error, el error que me marca es el siguiente:
Rum-time error 5345
word cannot obtain the data for the link

Comment: Puedes tratar añadiendo un delay un poco más grande?. A mí el código me funciona....

Comment: Lo que puedo notar es que aveces hace la ejecución completa y en ocaciones no, aun haciendo el delay más grande